# What is the equivalent of container_of in Delphi?

Tags: c++, delphi, type-conversion, offset, pascal

I am translating code from C++ source code to delphi language. What exactly does this resource do and how can I write it in delphi ?

```
#define container_of(inner, outer_t, elem) ((outer_t*)((char*)(inner)-offsetof(outer_t, elem)))
#define to_output_file_callback(_o) container_of((_o), struct output_file_callback, out)
```

Comment: Do you understand the C++ code? If not, then your first step is to make sure you fully *do* understand the C++ code. (If you need help and cannot find anything on the WWW, it may be a good idea to ask a pure-C++ SO question about that.) After that, you need to implement the same thing in Delphi. (If you need help and cannot find anything on the WWW, it may be a good idea to ask a pure-Delphi SO question about that. Since you know exactly what the code should do, you can describe your problem without even mentioning C++.)

Comment: This might help explain it: https://radek.io/2012/11/10/magical-container_of-macro/

Comment: Note that that macro has some problems; there are many situations in C++ where it won't do whatever it is that it's supposed to do.